# Components of a CRT whine

Tags: crt

I noticed something as a kid with my Atari 2600 (and better ears).

We can hear the 15khz horizontal freq but I noticed that the whine changes slightly (while the line frequency doesn’t) based on the background that was drawn.

It was very clear with these games since most backgrounds had large flat areas drawn in a single color. Games in the Atari days were changing their background color regularly when unattended to protect the screens from burnout.

As the changes would happen (for example the background going from solid green to solid blue), something was changing in the whine sound. Its frequency was obviously the same but it just felt different which probably means that transformer may have picked noise from somewhere else.

Can anyone explain what it could have been?

Comment: *whine changes slightly (while the line frequency doesn’t)* The frequency *components* definitely change (otherwise chances are you wouldn't have heard it).

Comment: The horizontal transformer also supplies the HT acceleration voltage. Gross brightness changes will change the HT current which will change the load on the horizontal transformer and the amplitude of the whine.

Comment: some of the video related sounds came through the audio stage

Comment: @jsotola, yes there was that too, but even without the TV sound on, you could hear the whine change.

Comment: @user_1818839, it is true, the whine would go much louder on some colors

Comment: anyone care to explain the close request? was it the wrong site for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> whine changes slightly (while the line frequency doesn’t)
> Its frequency was obviously the same

The frequency *components* of the whine definitely change (otherwise chances are you wouldn't have heard it). To little surprise, when you modulate the intensity of something with a temporally periodic thing (e.g. a periodic background), you modulate the tone!

Think of this: the whine comes from something (usually, transformer coils) moving due to a high-frequency (15 kHz) changing current; \$x_1(t) = \sin(2\pi f_1 t)\$.

If that current, for example, also changes at row frequency/2 (e.g., 1 kHz/2), because you're drawing the left half of the screen black and the right one white, \$x_2(t) = \operatorname{Squarewave}(2\pi f_2 t)\$ then your resulting acoustic signal is simply the product of both, \$x(t)=x_1(t)\cdot x_2(t)\$.

Now, a squarewave (like any periodic signal) is composed of a countable sum of cosines:

$$x_2(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\cos((2n -1)2\pi f_2 t)}{2n -1},$$

so that the product is simply

$$x(t)=x_1(t)x_2(t) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\cos(2\pi f_1t)\cos((2n -1) 2\pi f_2 t)}{2n -1},$$

which, thanks to trigonometry, simply is

\begin{align}
x(t)&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac12\frac{\cos(2\pi f_1t+(2n -1)2\pi f_2 t)+\cos(2\pi f_1 t - (2n -1)2\pi f_2 t)}{2n -1}\\
&=\frac 12\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{\cos(2\pi (f_1+(2n -1)f_2) t)+\cos(2\pi (f_1-(2n -1)f_2) t)}{2n -1},\\
\end{align}

so instead of 15 kHz, you hear new frequency components at 15 kHz \$\pm\$1 kHz, 3 kHz, 5 kHz, and so on, so you've got whine frequency components at 2, 4, …, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, … kHz. The strongest parts are still the ones "close" to the original unmoodulated whine (if your modulating signal was indeed a square wave).

So: yep, there were most definitely frequencies in the whine that were caused by the modulation of the load due to image content!

Answer (score 1):

In addition to its main function of obtaining the horizontal deflection, the flyback transformer was used to produce many auxiliary voltages for the circuitry around the crt (vertical output stage, sound output stage, colour output stage, high voltage, screen grid voltage, etc.). It could be that a change in the load produced a change in the noise emitted by the flyback transformer.

Comment: I was responding the same. A white screen needs more power than a black one so the duty cycle in the flyback regulator (which coincidentally *is* the horizontal sync frequency)  get wider and the tone audibly changes